# CakePHP 2.0 AclExtras Prints HTML code in shell

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, acl

I am trying to setup ACL based on the tutorial in the 2.0 book, but I get HTML script when i run

```
./Console/cake AclExtras.AclExtras aco_sync
```

It's really long to post here. In my bootstrap.php file I have

```
CakePlugin::load('AclExtras');
```

And in my AppController i have

```
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');
```

I have also tried to go without inputting the plugin to see what happens, and when i do something like this:

```
$this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers');
```

I get this error:

```
Warning (512): DbAcl::allow() - Invalid node [CORE\Cake\Model\Permission.php, line 176]
```

Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your ACO table populated correctly?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your ACO table is populated with atleast an entry 'controllers', with no parent_id.
2. Make sure the first argument of allow is a valid argument, in your case, `$group` should be a Group object, set with a proper group ID. E.g.

   ```
   $group = $this->User->Group;
   $group->id = 1;
   ```

(if you only set `$group` to be an integer, you're definitely going to get the error you're getting, so be sure to check this!)

1. Make sure the second argument is a valid argument (valid alias for example).